# Moving inline JavaScript code to an external file

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to make a Google Chrome extension, which doesn't allow for inline JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function one() {
        window.location.href = 'https://youtube.com/feed/subscriptions';
    }

    var d = new Date();
    var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    document.getElementById("demo").textContent = days[d.getDay()];
</script>
```

This is what I had as inline JavaScript code and I converted it to:

```
function one() {
    window.location.href = 'https://youtube.com/feed/subscriptions';
}
document.getElementById('linkOne').onclick = one;

var d = new Date();
var days =
["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
document.getElementById("demo").textContent = days[d.getDay()];
```

Chrome won't allow you to call external JavaScript functions, i.e "one()" as it falls under inline JavaScript code. I tried to call the function using the text 'linkOne' instead, but to no avail.

Comment: Have you imported the script reference on your page?

Comment: Is the problem that you want to override inline function with the one in a .js file?
Is the .js file referenced after the inline code (like bottom in the body) ?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know why you are using location.href to forward to another page. This, in your case, can be done with a simple `<a href="...">`.

I wrote a small HTML markup and put your JavaScript source in `foo.js`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Your demo content -->
    <div id="demo"></div>
    <!-- Your link -->
    <a href="#" id="linkOne">link</a>
    <!-- Your JavaScript file -->
    <script src="foo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```